# Get single object from array using JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
var frequencies = [{id:124,name:'qqq'}, 
                  {id:589,name:'www'}, 
                  {id:45,name:'eee'},
                  {id:567,name:'rrr'}];
```

I need to get an object from the array above by the `id` value.

For example I need to get the object with id = 45.

I tried this:

```
var t = frequencies.map(function (obj) { return obj.id==45; });
```

But I didn't get the desired object.

How can I implement it using JavaScript prototype functions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) not `map()`

```
var t = frequencies.filter(function (obj) { 
    return obj.id==45; 
})[0];
```

Comment: Is filter method works in InternetExplorer?

Comment: @Michael: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility .

Comment: Filter method return array(a single object array), any idea how can return object not array?

Comment: Yes. As filter will return an array. So you can easily user array[0] to get the product. 
That means if an array of single object is like singleObjectArray = [{name: "laptop"}]...
You can easily extract the object from the array like--

singleObject = singleObjectArray[0];

Comment: You should use find because it returns the object instead of an array.

Answer (score 32):

If your `id`'s are unique you can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var frequencies = [{"id":124,"name":"qqq"},{"id":589,"name":"www"},{"id":45,"name":"eee"},{"id":567,"name":"rrr"}];
                  
var result = frequencies.find(function(e) {
  return e.id == 45;
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Great! `find()` is perfect as it only returns a single entry from an array :-)